# WPF border style trows an InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my project I have created a file (styles.xaml) which contains all my styles I'm using in my application. I have tried to create the following style for my border controls.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyBackgroundTemplate">
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
         <GradientStop Color="#FF2A2A2A" Offset="1"/>
         <GradientStop Color="#FF4E4E4E"/>
    </LinearGradientBrush>
</DataTemplate>

<Style x:Key="BorderBackground" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource MyBackgroundTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```

In my MainWindow.xaml file I'm using the style this way:

```
<Border Grid.Column="4" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="10" BorderThickness="1" Margin="5" Style="{DynamicResource BorderBackground}"/>
```

I'm getting the following error when I'm running my application:

**InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.DataTemplate' to type 'System.Windows.Media.Brush'.**

Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? How can I use this style in my MainWindow.xaml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error already states, a `Background` is of type `Brush`, so you cannot assign a `DataTemplate`. Remove the `DataTemplate` tags and adapt its name and refer to it in your style.

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MyBackgroundBrush" EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
   <GradientStop Color="#FF2A2A2A" Offset="1"/>
   <GradientStop Color="#FF4E4E4E"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

If you do not need to reuse the `LinearGradientBrush`, you can inline it in your style.

```
<Style x:Key="BorderBackground" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
   <Setter Property="Background">
      <Setter.Value>
         <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF2A2A2A" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF4E4E4E"/>
         </LinearGradientBrush>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's just what I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

In case you insist to use resource binding:

```xml
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="MyBackgroundTemplate" EndPoint="0.5,1" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox" StartPoint="0.5,0">
     <GradientStop Color="#FF2A2A2A" Offset="1"/>
     <GradientStop Color="#FF4E4E4E"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>

<Style x:Key="BorderBackground" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MyBackgroundTemplate}"/>
</Style>
```